# NameError: name 'api' is not defined

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

Im trying to develop my first module on odoo 9.0 following the documentation and a developer manual for odoo, using the "TO-DO Tasks" example, but im having problems when I try to add a functionality to one of my buttons, in the manual says I have to add this code to my class file (todo_model.py).

```
@api.one
def do_toggle_done(self):
    self.is_done = not self.is_done
    return True
```

But when I update the module on Odoo I got this message:

> NameError: name 'api' is not defined

This is my todo_model.py

```
# -*- encoding utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models,fields

class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _name   =   "todo.task"
    name    =   fields.Char('Description', required=True)
    is_done =   fields.Boolean('Done?')
    active  =   fields.Boolean('Active?', default=True)

    @api.one
    def do_toggle_done(self):
         self.is_done = not self.is_done
         return True
```

Best regards.

Comment: I have corrected indentation. Please check if it's correct.

Comment: Is there a reason why you thing `api` should be defined? Where do you think it would be defined? I see no reason to believe that it should be defined given your code.

Comment: It works!, my function still not works but i dont have the error now, I can continue following the manual Thanks a lot @MYGz

Comment: I've Additionally added the "api" import to the second line

Comment: The indentation of the my code on pycharm was different to the posted one so, Ive corrected the indentation and added the "api" to the imports and it works now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to import *api*

Try with following:

```
from openerp import api,models,fields
```

Comment: Yes I've added and it worked, thanks for the clarification.